# Admob for Android Andengine Game

Tags: java, android, admob, andengine

I created an android game by andengine.And I wanna add Admob ad to the game.I used code which below.And I got an error which is in picture. http://s16.postimage.org/rz6fbr2l1/Untitled.png

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

but i added in manifest like above.So what's the problem?

```
 protected void onSetContentView() {


     final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
     final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
             new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                          FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

     final AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "PUBLISHER_ID");

     adView.refreshDrawableState();
     adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
     final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams =
             new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                          FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                          Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.TOP);


     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
     adView.loadAd(adRequest);

     this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
     mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine);

     final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
             new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

     frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
     frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);

     this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);
 }
```

Comment: change api level to 13 and check

Comment: didn't work. there is the same error

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

Comment: when i do that,nothing is visible...

Comment: Samir's advice is correct.  When you change your activity to use Samir's suggested configChanges and API 13 or higher, what do the logs say about ads?

Comment: Blog linked to by original answer no longer exists - this one - http://coding-dump.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/admob-with-andengine.html is still live though.